# How can I catch mercurial errors in bash?

Tags: bash, mercurial

How can I get the result of a `hg update` command in bash and use the results?

I'm interested in a true/false value or something similar. One of the errors I'm interested on is unknown revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I run it in a subshell and catch the output and exit code

```
result=$(hg update 2>&1)
exit_code=$?
```

then

```
case $exit_code in
0)
  success
  ;;
[1-5])
  failure x
  ;;
[6-9])
  failure y
  ;;
255)
  failure z
  ;;
*) # Default
  echo "it's a trap"
  ;;
esac
```

Or you can if you are interested in true/false status run

```
result=$(hg update 2>&1) && echo "Success"
```

or

```
result=$(hg update 2>&1) || echo "Failure"
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `$?` give you what you want?  Try "`echo $?`" after running the `hg update` command.  Typically, zero means "ok" and non-zero means something went wrong.